# No puedo conectarme a la DB con una variable traida desde otro activity

Tags: android, kotlin

Tengo una variable "email_post" guardada en un companion object en el Activity1 que esta vacia, dentro de este mismo activity en una funcion setup() rescato con un bundle el valor de email desde el Activity anterior y la guardo en "email"

```
companion object{
    var email_post = ""
}

 var bundle = intent.extras
 email_post = bundle?.getString("email").toString()
```

Luego en el Activity3 llamo a la variable y la imprimo en un TextView

```
var emailUser = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.emailUser)
val email = Activity1.email_post
emailUser.setText(email)
```

Hasta ahí ningún problema ... pero si intento usar la variable email como id para conectarme a una base de datos de Firebase la app se cae ...

```
db.collection("usuarios").document(email).get().addOnSuccessListener {
nombre.setText(it.get("nombre") as String?)
apellido.setText(it.get("apellido") as String?)
}
```

agradecería ideas o ayuda para solucionar este tema ... Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

El valor que envias en el `Intent` es demasiado importante sea recibido dentro de onCreate() de la Activity destino, de otra forma no obtendràs el valor correcto.

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle){
   super.onCreate(saveInstanceState)
    ...
    ...

    email_post = intent.getStringExtra("email")

}
```